# How to pass Vector of generic class as an argument?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, vector

I have these classes (in different files):

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
  ...
}
public class Application {
     public static <T> T getMax (Vector<Comparable<T>> v){
    }
}
```

I try to pull this off:

```
public static void main(){
    Vector<Student> v = new Vector();
    v.add(new Student());
    v.add(new Student());
    Application app = new Application();
    app.getMax(v);// <--- error is here
}
```

But i get the error:

> The method getMax(Vector<Comparable>) in the type Application is
> not applicable for the arguments (Vector)

What am i missing?

Comment: "*`public static <T> T getMax (Vector<Comparable<T>> v){`*" looks weird. I would suggest to use `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T getMax (Vector<T> v){`. --- "*`Vector<Student> v = new Vector();`*" - [Don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). --- `Vector`s are specifically designed for concurrency. If we do not need this, we can use a `List` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Basically repeating what @Turing85 mentioned, but the issue is in your `Application.getMax()`. You do not want to do `Vector<Comparable<T>>`, you want to do `Vector<T>` and then have the type parameter `T` be defined as `<T extends Comparable<T>>`. Here is what your corrected method header should look like.

`public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T getMax (Vector<T> v)`

---

When you say `Vector<Comparable<T>>`, you are saying that you want a `Vector` of `Comparable`. And I don't mean "Objects that implement Comparable", you are literally saying that the only acceptable types permitted into your Vector is the Comparable class - ***which invalidates any classes that implement Comparable***.

Here is an example of what I am saying.

```
Vector<Comparable<Integer>> comparables = new Vector<>();

//error - Integer is not a Comparable, it only IMPLEMENTS Comparable
comparables.add(12345);
```

```
Vector<Comparable<String>> comparables = new Vector<>();

//error - String is not a Comparable, it only IMPLEMENTS Comparable
comparables.add("abc");
```

```
Vector<Comparable<String>> comparables = new Vector<>();

Comparable<String> c =
    new Comparable<String>() {
            public int compareTo(String s) {
                return 0;
            }
        };

//OK - Comparable<String> is a Comparable, so it works
comparables.add(c);
```

That's why it is much easier to say `<T extends Comparable<T>>` and then just say `Vector<T>`. If we switch out the `getMax()` method header with the one I/Turing85 gave you, then your Application class should work easier.